# GetDriveType detects "Google Drive" as DRIVE_FIXED... how to exclude them?

Tags: delphi, winapi, hard-drive, getdrivetype

I have a little utility (on beloved Delphi) that monitors HardDisks FreeSpace

I use GetDriveType

The problem is that "Google Drives" are being recognized as DRIVE_FIXED
So I'm trying to manage how to identify this dirves, in order to exclude them... the workround so far is get drive name and find "google" in it's name.. but i think is not the clenest way.

```
procedure TFormSpace.CreaLabels;
var
    Type, i, n: Word;
    LblDummy: TLabel;
    Candidate: string;
begin
    Max:=0;
    i:=1;
    repeat
        Candidate:=chr(ord('c')+i-1) + ':\';
        Type:=GetDriveType(pchar(Candidate));
        if (Tipo=DRIVE_FIXED) then begin
            //Do something
        end;
        i:=i+1;
    until (i=MaxItems); 
end;
```

Thanks!

On an example setup:

```
c:\ -> 1TB SSD
d:\ -> 2TB SSD
f:\  -> Maped network drive
g:\ -> google drive, replicated con "d:\Drive"
```

the above code will return:
`C:\ D:\ G:\`

But expected result is:
`C:\ D:\`
(just real physical drives)

Comment: Well, you need to find another discriminant with another API, may something like GetVolumeInformationW:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw

Comment: @SimonMourier, actually good idea.
I still don't have reputation to answer myself, but:
Seems the flag is `FILE_SUPPORTS_REMOTE_STORAGE` (value 0x00000100)

Comment: Here's the study, if anyone is interested: [link](https://i.imgur.com/VgjR7gC.png)

Comment: You don't need any reputation for answering. Exception to that rule are some highly visited questions with many answers that have attracted low quality answers or spam in the past. They are protected and you need at least 10 reputation points to answer. But those questions have blue banner on top stating they are protected. If you have found the solution, you can freely post your answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was the flag FILE_SUPPORTS_REMOTE_STORAGE (value 0x00000100)

A study can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AcYK.png)

or here [image: here]